# Apache VirtualHost settings for multiple servers on 1 IP address with multiple domains with SSL for each domain

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

How do I configure my apache settings to serve 3 physical servers on 1 IP address, and on each of those servers exists multiple domains with SSL. I have multi-domain SSL certificates for each server.

Do I need to use the same settings for each httpd file on each physical server?

How do I configure my router for port forwarding?

My current configuration is below. I would appreciate any errors in my settings being brought to my attention and advised how to do it properly.

---

```
Server1 httpd:

<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

###  SERVER1 host  ###
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot D:/public_html
    ServerName server1domain1.org
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### server1domain1.org VirtualHost ####
            
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server1domain1.org"
ServerName server1domain1.org
ServerAlias www.server1domain1.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server1domain1.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain1.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain1.org.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### SSL server1domain1.org VirtualHost ####
            
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server1domain1.org"
ServerName server1domain1.org
ServerAlias www.server1domain1.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server1domain1.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain1.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain1.org.log" combined
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/server1domain1.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/server1domain1.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/server1domain1-ca_bundle.crt"
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### server1domain2.org VirtualHost ####
            
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server1domain2.org"
ServerName server1domain2.org
ServerAlias server1domain2.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server1domain2.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain2.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain2.org.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### SSL server1domain2.org VirtualHost ####
            
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server1domain2.org"
ServerName server1domain2.org
ServerAlias server1domain2.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server1domain2.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain2.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server1domain2.org.log" combined
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/server1domain2.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/server1domain2.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/server1domain2-ca_bundle.crt"
</VirtualHost>

***

Server2 httpd


<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>


###  SERVER2 host  ###
<VirtualHost server2domain1.com:8081>
    DocumentRoot D:/public_html
    ServerName server2domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### server2domain1.com VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.5:8081>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server2domain1.com"
ServerName server2domain1.com
ServerAlias www.server2domain1.com
<Directory "D:/public_html/server2domain1.com">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain1.com.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain1.com.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### SSL server2domain2.com VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.5:444>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server2domain1.com"
ServerName server2domain1.com
ServerAlias www.server2domain1.com
<Directory "D:/public_html/server2domain1.com">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain1.com.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain1.com.log" combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server2domain1-multi-certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server2domain1-multi-ca_bundle.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/server2domain1-multi-private.key"
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### server2domain2.org VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.5:8081>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server2domain2.org"
ServerName server2domain2.org
ServerAlias www.server2domain2.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server2domain2.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain2.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain2.org.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### SSL server2domain2.org VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.5:444>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server2domain2.org"
ServerName server2domain2.org
ServerAlias www.server2domain2.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server2domain2.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain2.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server2domain2.org.log" combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server2domain2-multi-certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server2domain2-multi-ca_bundle.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/server2domain2-multi-private.key"
</VirtualHost>

***

Server3 httpd

<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

###  SERVER3 host  ###
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:8080>
    DocumentRoot D:/public_html
    ServerName server3domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### server3domain1.com VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:8080>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server3domain1.com"
ServerName server3domain1.com
ServerAlias www.server3domain1.com
<Directory "D:/public_html/server3domain1.com">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain1.com.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain1.com.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### SSL server3domain1.com VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:445>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server3domain1.com"
ServerName server3domain1.com
ServerAlias www.server3domain1.com
<Directory "D:/public_html/server3domain1.com">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain1.com.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain1.com.log" combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server3domain1-multi-certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server3domain1-multi-ca_bundle.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/server3domain1-multi-private.key"
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### server3domain2.org VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:8080>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server3domain2.org"
ServerName server3domain2.org
ServerAlias www.server3domain2.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server3domain2.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain2.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain2.org.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

####################################

#### SSL server3domain2.org VirtualHost ####
            

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:445>
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/server3domain2.org"
ServerName server3domain2.org
ServerAlias www.server3domain2.org
<Directory "D:/public_html/server3domain2.org">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain2.org.err"
CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/server3domain2.org.log" combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server3domain2-multi-certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server3domain2-multi-ca_bundle.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/server3domain2-multi-private.key"
</VirtualHost>

####################################
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing extensive research and learning that I needed to create a reverse proxy server (FREEDOM.LOCAL), I hired a server expert to set that up for me. After adding "Listen 8080" to my httpd file on the reverse proxy server, the changes that he made to the vhosts.conf file on the reverse proxy server are below:

```
# Redirect to https
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:80>
  ServerName freedom.local
  ServerAlias *
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
  
  <Location /phpmyadmin>
    Require all denied
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# reverse proxy to TRUTH server
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:443>
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com domain1.org www.domain1.org domain2.com www.domain2.com domain2.org www.domain2.org

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/domain1-multi-certificate.crt"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/domain1-multi-ca_bundle.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/domain1-multi-private.key"
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.11:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.11:80/
  
  <Location /phpmyadmin>
    Require all denied
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# reverse proxy to PROSPERITY server
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:443>
  ServerName domain3.network
  ServerAlias www.domain3.social domain3.media www.domain3.media domain3.news www.domain3.news domain3.network www.domain3.network mail.domain3.network domain4.org www.domain4.org domain5.com www.domain5.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/domain3-multi.crt"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/domain3-multi-ca_bundle.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/domain3-multi.key"
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.13:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.13:80/
  
  <Location /phpmyadmin>
    Require all denied
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# reverse proxy to PASSION server
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:443>
  ServerName domain8.org
  ServerAlias www.domain8.org domain6.org www.domain6.org domain7.org www.domain7.org

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADD:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGD:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/multi-domain6.crt"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_crt/multi-domain6-ca_bundle.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/server/apache/conf/ssl_key/multi-domain6.key"
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.9:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.9:80/
  
  <Location /phpmyadmin>
    Require all denied
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

####################################

## PhpMyAdmin

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:8080>
    DocumentRoot "D:/public_html"
    ServerName freedom.local
    ServerAlias *
    <Directory "D:/public_html">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the content of one of the slave servers (PASSION.LOCAL) vhosts.conf file:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

###  PASSION host  ###

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/domain8.org"
    ServerName domain8.org
    ServerAlias www.domain8.org
    <Directory "D:/public_html/domain8.org">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/domain8.org.err"
    CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/domain8.org.log" combined
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv HTTPS on
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/domain6.org"
    ServerName domain6.org
    ServerAlias www.domain6.org
    <Directory "D:/public_html/domain6.org">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/domain6.org.err"
    CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/domain6.org.log" combined
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv HTTPS on
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/public_html/domain7.org"
    ServerName domain7.org
    ServerAlias www.domain7.org
    <Directory "D:/public_html/domain7.org">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "D:/server/apache/logs/domain7.org.err"
    CustomLog "D:/server/apache/logs/domain7.org.log" combined
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv HTTPS on
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>


####################################

## PhpMyAdmin

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.9:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/public_html"
    ServerName passion.local
    ServerAlias *
    <Directory "D:/public_html">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```